# how to check folder size in windows through command prompt

Tags: file, cmd, directory

how to check folder size in windows through command prompt

say for example in `C:\Windows` there are many files and folders.

How to get the size of these files and folders

Is there any command similar to `du -sg *` in unix?

I have tried dir which will give the file not folders

Comment: du -sg * or du -sh *?

Comment: du -sg * not du -sh *

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a IN ('dir /s') DO (
 IF "%%b"=="File(s)" SET $files=%%a&SET $bytes=%%c
 IF "%%b"=="Dir(s)" SET $dirs=%%a&SET $free=%%c
)
SET $

GOTO :EOF
```

This should set some variables of interest.

You should be able to insert a pusd/popd bracket

```
PUSHD someotherdirectory
for /f ....
...
)
POPD
...
```

to read the characteristics of `someotherdirectory` if you prefer.

Comment: This is giving the total size and total folders and total files.. I require the size of each parent folder.

Comment: My crystal ball is in for repairs at present. Perhaps `dir/s |findstr "\ bytes"|more` would suit better?

Comment: Given exception!
`'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

Size of Windows folders - sorted and listed by MB - high to low

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\windows"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /ad /b ') do call :size "%%~fa"
sort /r < "%temp%\dirsize.tmp" |more
del "%temp%\dirsize.tmp"
popd
pause
goto :eof

:size
for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('dir /s "%~1" 2^>nul ^|find " File(s) "') do set "n=%%b"
set "n=%n:,=%"

>"%temp%\VBS.vbs" echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^) : Wscript.echo int((%n%/1024/1024))
for /f "delims=" %%z in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\VBS.vbs"') do set "dirsize=%%z"
del "%temp%\VBS.vbs"

set dirsize=               %dirsize%
set dirsize=%dirsize:~-15%
>>"%temp%\dirsize.tmp" echo %dirsize% "%~1"
```

Comment: It is giving Error

'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you used a variable called `PATH` ?

Comment: I asked you a question, because the only reason to get those errors you mentioned is if the Windows install is corrupted, or the `PATH` variable has been changed or reused.

Comment: the PATH is printed as `PATH=E:\Program files\Java\jre\bin;E:\Program files\ant\bin`. Is this correct? If not how can i change it?  Windows is installed on C: and the JRE is installed on E:

Comment: No, it's not correct.  You have lost the system folders and every system file will fail. How did you change it?  Is the environment for your user changed to what you have shown, in the `path` variable, or is it just changed in a batch file that you are using?

Comment: from your bat file I'm getting a figure of 20228 for around 72 items, but in windows folder I have 70 folders summing to 13 GB. I don't think this bat is giving correct output.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to access those folders?  I can't see your system so I don't know what folders you are referring to.  It is working ok in my Windows 8.1 system.  Right click the batch file and `run as administrator`